# C++ Computer guesses users number within 7 guesses

Tags: c++, loops, binary-search

The following prompt was on my intro to Computer Science course final.

**Write a program according to the following description:
The user picks the number and tells the computer whether its guesses are too high or too low until the computer guesses it right.
Done correctly, the program should be able to determine the number within 7 guesses (assuming the human doesn't cheat).
(Hint: binary search – try exactly halfway between the possible numbers left).
Provide test values and expected results for your program.**

How can I get it to guess within 7 attempts?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
 int min,max;
 cout<<"To begin guessing game, enter maximum and minimum game parameters (positive integers).\n";
 cout<<"Enter minimum value : ";
 cin>>min;
 cout<<"Enter maximum value : ";
 cin>>max;
 cout<< "Choose a number between "<<min<< " and "<<max<<" : ";
 int userNum;// create variable A
 cin>>userNum;//User inputs number 
 int compGuess;
 srand(time(NULL));
 compGuess = rand() % max + min;//computer produces random number between 1 and 100 and stores in variable b

    
        while (userNum != compGuess)//compare variable to a to b
        {
            cout<<"Computer guesses "<<compGuess;
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"Is your number higher? (enter y for yes or n for no) : ";
            char c;//char size variable created called c
            cin>>c;//User input (y or n)  overwrites c
            bool d;//bool size variable created called d
                if (c=='y')
                    {
                        d=true;
                        min=compGuess;
                    }
                else  
                    {
                        d=false;
                        max=compGuess;
                    }
                    
                if (d)
                    {
                        compGuess=(compGuess+max)/2;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        compGuess=(min+compGuess)/2;  
                    }
        }   
        cout<< "Your number is "<<compGuess;   
        
}
```

Comment: So what is your question, exactly?

Comment: The provided description of binary search is sufficient to figure it out for the sake of an exam question. Exams that simply test memorization aren't all that great.

Comment: It looks like you also didn't learn the difference between values, like `'y'`, and variable identifiers, like `y`. Or the point of using meaningful names for your variables.

Comment: You can't ask the player what number they're thinking of. The whole point of the game is that the program doesn't know.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to think from the point of view of the computer, who doesn't know the answer.

You (the computer) gain information when you get answers from the player. The information is the range that the unknown number is in. That is, a minimum and maximum. Initialize it to (0, 100). Update this each time you get answer from the player. Repeat until min = max.

Beware of [off-by-one bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).